# Find String out of String with Data in Python

Tags: python, string, find

I need to find a String out of String from an JSON data. I do have given an Data to search for the right string.
Here is what i have done so far:

```
description = "Range: 1 = RED_STRAWBERRYS, 2 = WHITE_STRAWBERRYS, 3 = PINK_RASPBERRY, 4 = BLUE_BERRY"
data = "4"
data_plus_one = "5"
msg = (description[description.find(str(data))+len(description[0:4]):description.rfind(", "+data_plus_one +" =")])
print(msg)
```

It does work. If I search for RED_STRAWBERRYS I do have the data = 1. And I get it back. But if i look for the last element. In this case for BLUE_BERRY then I get "BLUE_BERR" back without the last Letter. Does someone now a better way than this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex approach to generate a dictionary with numbers as the keys and fruits as the values might work here:

```py
description = "Range: 1 = RED_STRAWBERRYS, 2 = WHITE_STRAWBERRYS, 3 = PINK_RASPBERRY, 4 = BLUE_BERRY"
d = dict(re.findall(r'(\d+) = ([^,]+)', description))
print("one:   " + d["1"])  # one:   RED_STRAWBERRYS
print("three: " + d["3"])  # three: PINK_RASPBERRY
```